# Sideways scroll in a flex child element with fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've made a sidebar layout with using css flexbox and would like to affix the sidebar position, but allow the main content area to both horizontally and vertically scroll. Using `overflow: hidden` on the parent container and `overflow:auto` on the content container allows for vertical scrolling, but does not allow for horizontal scrolling. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/emceelamb-the-typescripter/pen/XWYLaoE)

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #f00;
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex-basis: 250px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wide-content {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wide-content">
      <p>
        "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
        blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
        and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
        pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
      </p>
      <p>
        "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
        blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
        and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
        pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, using `overflow: auto` on the parent container allows for vertical scrolling and horizontal scrolling, but the sidebar moves as well. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/emceelamb-the-typescripter/pen/xxzoXqe)

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #f00;
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex-basis: 250px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wide-content {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wide-content">
      <p>
        "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
        blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
        and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
        pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
      </p>
      <p>
        "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
        blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
        and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
        pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a solution using flexbox to allow for both vertical and horizontal scrolling while keeping the sidebar in the same place?

Thank you!

Comment: Put your CSS and HTML here in the question so we can best assist you here.  Consider a snippet to do so.  I added one as an example

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I added examples as codepen links.

Comment: Can't you just set position: fixed on the side-bar, and have a padding-left on the container, the same amount as the width of the sidebar?

Comment: @WimMertens, Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm hoping to use flexbox since I still would want to have auto margins for the container to center it on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of ugly but perhaps you can style it better. sticky left top;

Might need to adjust the side bar size a bit; clean up the overflow etc.
But perhaps a good starting point with some stripped down CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  height: 110vh;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #ff8888;
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.content {
  height: 150vh;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.wide-content {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wide-content">
      <p>
        "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
        blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
        and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
        pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
      </p>
      <p>
        "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
        blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
        and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
        pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't think `position: sticky` will work for this. I'd like to keep the container centered in the page.

Comment: I adjusted the body ` overflow: hidden;` to remove the window scroll bars - you may have to work with the sidebar and container height a bit to get an aesthetic visual you like here.

Comment: I think those additions got it to a good starting point for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is `overflow-x: scroll` and `overflow-y: scroll`

```
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately this did not work. The overflow-x still does not scroll. On a side note I understand that the `overflow:auto` would apply for both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great example for `display: grid`. You can designate a column for the sidebar and then set the vertical and horizontal scroll bars for `<div class="content">`

Generally, `display: grid` is great for static layouts while `display: flex` works better with responsive layouts, in this case, it sounds like you're working on something static.

It's a little bit cleaner and you also have your horizontal scrolling. I'm not sure if it's best practice to allow horizontal scrolling for large bodies of text, so if you change your mind just go ahead and delete the `p` styling in the CSS.

```
p {
    width: 600px;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

p {
    width: 600px;
}

.container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template: auto / 150px auto;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #f00;
    border: 1px red solid;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wide-content {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: lightpink;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wide-content">
            <p>
                "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
                blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
                and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
                pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
            </p>
            <p>
                "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal
                blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled
                and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that
                pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I reduced the overall size of `<div class="container">` to allow for more scrolling, but of course you can just change the values to whatever you like.